# update SwiftPM with XcodeGen

Tags: ios, swift, swiftpm, xcodegen

I'm using [XcodeGen](https://github.com/yonaskolb/XcodeGen) to automate the project generation and I'm new to XcodeGen. Can anyone help me how to update any SwiftPM dependency (ex: Facebook or SDWebImage) when XcodeGen is integrated?

Currently when I update any SwiftPM dependency and run `xcodegen generate`, it reverts back to old version. Also, I don't see any update in my git also.

Can someone help me on this? If this is duplicate question, then please tag the original question.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Change version of package in packages field to new version. Example:

```
packages:
  SDWebImage:
    url: https://github.com/SDWebImage/SDWebImage
    # from: <new_version>
    from: 5.12.5
```